# Calling a method and making object of an unknown class in Java

Tags: java, class, object, package

I have a problem with going back and adding to the main loop of my game, This task would be eliminated if I could create objects from classes I don't know about.

Right now I have:

```
if (Monesers.Zombie.canBeCreated(world,objects)){
    Zombie.add(new Monster())
}

if (Monesers.Sceleton.canBeCreated(world,objects)){
    objects.add(new Monster())
}
```

I am looking for something I can loop to all classes without mentioning the name the class so I don't have to copy the same code over and over for every new thing in the game.

Comment: not very much clear to me. can you please describe more clearly about what you want

Comment: What you need is probably reflection, although your question is a bit vague...

Comment: @NilsH I added more detail

Comment: I agree that you should tell more, including the rationale behind this desire. I fear that this really is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and that you may not be asking the correct question.

Comment: You are still only giving cryptic bits of information and not telling the fuller story. I fear that you're going about this all wrong, but even worse that your lack of clarity of your question will get it closed soon. Please tell the *whole* story. Please show pertinent code.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Foll Of Eels I tried to re write the question, and I think than now it makes more seance than before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection will get you somewhere... I don't know if it's the preferred method though.

You could do something like this. Have every monster type implement an interface, something like this:

```
public interface Monster {

    public boolean canBeCreated ( );

}
```

Then you could have a monster creator, something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class MonsterCreator {

    private Monster[] monsterTypes;

    public MonsterCreator ( ) {
        monsterTypes = new Monster[2];
        monsterTypes[0] = new Zombie ( );
        monsterTypes[0] = new Skeleton ( );
    }

    public void tick ( ) {
        for ( Monster m : monsterTypes ) {
            if ( m.canBeCreated ( ) ) {
                try {
                    Constructor< ? >[] constr = m.getClass ( )
                        .getConstructors ( );
                    Monster toAdd = ( Monster ) constr[0].newInstance ( );
                    MonsterContainer.add ( toAdd );
                } catch ( InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                    | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace ( );
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It's worth a try... :)

Of course the thing with the monster types can be done neater with something like a map of enum constants linked to class types... Again, this is just for the sake of the example. Just wanted to get this posted before the question got closed!

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking fro bit it's better than before!